# Publishing to arxiv after submitting to conference while paper is under review

Tags: arxiv

The conference policy states that they accept submissions that have previously been posted on arXiv. However, there are no clear rules specified if the paper can be submitted to arxiv *after* the submission to the conference has been made. Can the paper be submitted to arxiv while it is under review at the conference?

The rule is stated as below:

> Submission is permitted for papers that are available as a technical report (or similar, e.g., in arXiv). In this case we suggest the authors not cite the report, so as to preserve anonymity.

Comment: Generally yes, but you need to check with the conference to get an authoritative answer.

Comment: Please provide the text you refer to.

Comment: "The conference policy states the acceptance of arxiv" -- does this mean the conference says its OK? If so, what's the question? In general, submitting to arXiv is fine; it's a pre-print server, not a publication venue, but you have to follow your conference/journal's policy

Comment: @cag51 yeah its says its ok if it has been submitted to arxiv already but to keep the anonymity we don't specify about it. However, I am not sure if it's ok to submit to arxiv after I have made the submission, while its under review. Should it be fine as well ?

Comment: @scaaahu sorry I will rectify it but I only mean to ask if prior to submission is allowed then will post submission be fine as well ?

Comment: @scaaahu thanks for pointing out. I have added it as well.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Good luck!